# Checking the validation of a JSON response with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, automation

I want to check these endpoints if the answer is other than 0 it is ok but if 0 it is not ok.
After I have done it these checks, I want to send the result to an 'outlook' email, can anyone help me with it.

This is my code so far.

```
import json, requests, urllib.parse, re
from termcolor import colored
import numpy as np

cdwenv1 = 'cdwu' #Note that it only works with the http version right now
cdwenv2 = 'cdwp'

#Dev Static
cdwenv  = '' #leave empty

# static
cdwEndPoints = [
                 'http://cdwu/cdw/counterparties?count=true'
                ,'http://cdwu/identifier/assets?count=true'
                ,'http://cdwu/identifier/assetListings?count=true'
]

# Check that Counts are different from 0
import sys

def countsCDWdata(input: list, cdwenv1, flag=0):
   results = []
   for i, item in enumerate(input):
        result = []
        if '?' in item:
            cdwcounturl = item
        try:
            r = requests.get(cdwcounturl)
        except:
                print(cdwcounturl, colored('is erroring', 'red'))
        result.append([cdwenv1, r.text])
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write('\r Queried '+ str(i) + ' out of ' + str(len(input)))   
        results.append([re.findall('//.*?/.*?/(.*?)/',item)[0], result[0], result[0]])
   if flag == 1:
      return(results)
   df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['CDWEndpoint', 'CDW Env', 'Counts'])
   df['Status'] = np.where(df['Counts1'] != 0, colored('Ok', 'green'), colored('not Ok', 'red'))
   sys.stdout.flush()
   sys.stdout.write('\r')
   print(df)
```

I am getting this error:

```
http://cdwu/cdw/counterparties?count=true is erroring
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://cdwu/cdw/counterparties?count=true is erroring
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-797620017bbc> in <module>()
----> 1 countsCDWdata(cdwEndPoints, [cdwenv1])

<ipython-input-70-73176a33caf9> in countsCDWdata(input, cdwenv1, flag)
      9         except:
     10                 print(cdwcounturl, colored('is erroring', 'red'))
---> 11         result.append([cdwenv1, r.text])
     12         sys.stdout.flush()
     13         sys.stdout.write('\r Queried '+ str(i) + ' out of ' + str(len(input)))

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: The ```r``` variable is only assigned line 12 => You don't achieve the try, fall in the except =>  ```r``` kind of "doesn't exist". Which lead to this error. And look at the first line of the error ```http://cdwu/cdw/counterparties?count=true is erroring```, it looks like the error printing line 14.

Comment: Notwithstanding the previous comment, using *input* as a variable name is inadvisable

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import jsonschema
from jsonschema import validate

def validateJson(jsonData):
    try:
        validate(instance=jsonData, schema=studentSchema)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as err:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Please find the [official docs](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/) where `jsonschema.validate` is explained. One may require for the exception to not be caught at this level.